# Error when reading yahoofinancials JSON: Unexpected character found when decoding 'NaN'

Tags: python, json, yahoo-finance

I am trying to read a json, which I get from the python package 'yahoofinancials' (it pulls the data from Yahoo Finance):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials

yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials(ticker)
cash_statements = yahoo_financials.get_financial_stmts('annual', 'income')
cash_statements
pd.read_json(str(cash_statements).replace("'", '"'), orient='records')
```

However I get the error:
Unexpected character found when decoding 'NaN'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this command: `str(cash_statements).replace("'", '"')`.

You tried to **"convert"** from a **python dictionary** to a **json string**, by replacing single with double quotes, which does not properly work.

Use the `json.dump(cash_statements)` function for converting your dictionary object into a json string.

**Updated Code:**

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials

# ADJUSTMENT 1 - import json
import json


# just some sample data for testing
ticker = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'INTC']

yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials(ticker)
cash_statements = yahoo_financials.get_financial_stmts('annual', 'income')

# ADJUSTMENT 2 - dict to json
cash_statements_json = json.dumps(cash_statements)
pd.read_json(cash_statements_json, orient='records')
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the file is available or the file name is correct because I got the same error while reading a `.json` file that was not in that folder and located somewhere else.